# How can I convert multiple SQL records logs to one new single record?

Tags: sql, logging

I need to work with some logs and I realized they are saved on multiple SQL records.
For example :

[image: logs example]

As you can see, for the same "TRO_IdOrdre" I have different "TRO_TypeTrc" and so differents dates.
I know that each "TRO_TypeTrc" has a specific signification. For example :

- 1 : creation of the mission
- 2 : beginning of the mission
- 4 : end of the mission
  etc.

The problem is not every mission has the same number of lines. It can be created and never start or it can start and then cancelled.

So I would like to know if there is a way to transform all my table in a new table with something like that :

- Order Id
- Creation date
- Start date
- End date
- cancelled ? (yes/no)
- cancelled date

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select TRO_IdOrdre,
       max(case when TRO_TypeTrc = 1 then tro_date end),
       max(case when TRO_TypeTrc = 2 then tro_date end),
       max(case when TRO_TypeTrc = 6 then tro_date end),
       max(case when TRO_TypeTrc = 8 then tro_date end),
       coalesce(max(case when TRO_TypeTrc = 4 then 'Yes' end), 'No') as is_cancelled
from t
group by TRO_IdOrdre;
```

You can fill in the names of the columns.